# Find index of previous occurance of modality in (ordered) group

Tags: r, dplyr

It's easier to explain with an example. Consider this data:

```
library(dplyr)
n_data       = 20
set.seed(123)
data_standout = data.frame(group = sample(c('kids','monkeys','banana', 'latte'),
                                         size = n_data, replace=TRUE), 
                          time  = runif(n_data),
                          modality = sample(c('grande','small','large'),
                                            size = n_data, replace=TRUE),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data_standin  = data.frame(group = c('kids','monkeys','banana', 'latte'), 
                           time = runif(4, 0, min(data_standout$time)), 
                           modality = rep('small', 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_final    = bind_rows(data_standout, data_standin)
```

Ok. Now let us consider one group in particular: the monkeys.

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   group [1]
    group       time modality
    <chr>      <dbl>    <chr>
1 monkeys 0.09211798    small
2 monkeys 0.17505265   grande
3 monkeys 0.32037324    large
4 monkeys 0.43489274    large
5 monkeys 0.46677904    small
6 monkeys 0.48861303   grande
7 monkeys 0.78229430    small
```

The groups are ordered in time and start each with an 
occurrence of `modality == small`.

Now, I want to create a new column. Each row in that column 
should indicate the index of the last occurrence of `small` 
within the same group.

So for the monkeys group, the values of that column should be:

```
(NA, 1,1,1,1,5,5)
```

Speed is not a major requirement but dplyr is (the rest of the data pipline is in dplyr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `monkeys` data as an example:

```
monkeys %>% 
    arrange(time) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(small_idx = lag(cummax(ifelse(modality == 'small', seq_along(modality), 0))))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   group [1]
#    group       time modality small_idx
#   <fctr>      <dbl>   <fctr>     <dbl>
#1 monkeys 0.09211798    small        NA
#2 monkeys 0.17505265   grande         1
#3 monkeys 0.32037324    large         1
#4 monkeys 0.43489274    large         1
#5 monkeys 0.46677904    small         1
#6 monkeys 0.48861303   grande         5
#7 monkeys 0.78229430    small         5
```

---

*Details*:

`ifelse` create an index vector which if `modality` is not small, has values of zero;

```
with(monkeys, ifelse(modality == 'small', seq_along(modality), 0))
# [1] 1 0 0 0 5 0 7
```

`cummax` gives the max index of `small` seen so far:

```
cummax(with(monkeys, ifelse(modality == 'small', seq_along(modality), 0)))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 5 5 7
```

`lag` gives max index of `small` seen before:

```
lag(cummax(with(monkeys, ifelse(modality == 'small', seq_along(modality), 0))))
# [1] NA  1  1  1  1  5  5
```

Comment: that's super cool: that trick (ifelse + cumsum) can easily be generalized to other related problems! Thanks a million